# Vue, invoke method using its name as a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a navbar I have to put a list of buttons. While some are links, others should call a method. (e.g. Home should link to /home and Log out should call a function logOut). Because of the large number of items, it is better to have an array with all the buttons/elements that should be rendered

```
  items: [
    { divider: true },
    { icon: "tasks", text: "Today", link: "/tasks" },
    { icon: "sticky-note", text: "Notes", link: "/notes" },
    { divider: true },
    { heading: "Label" },
    { icon: "code-branch", text: "Branch" },
    { divider: true },
    { icon: "user", text: "Account", link: "/profile" },
    { icon: "cog", text: "Settings" },
    { icon: "sign-out-alt", text: "Log out", action: "logOut" }
  ]
```

However, I am not sure how to call a method using its name(the last action in the array above).
I saw that in js I could use window[item.action]. Is there something similar in Vue? In other words something like @click="methods[item.action]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function to receive the method name and parameters and call the method in this function. You can see in this [example](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/wLbZpX)

```js
handleFunctionCall(functionName, event) {
        this[functionName](event)
    },
```

```html
<button v-else-if="item.action" @click="handleFunctionCall(item.action, $event)" >{{item.text}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

VueJS is still javascript so yes calling the method by its name should work, although I would suggest to use `this[*method_name_here*]();` to call the function (In the Vue controller I'm not sure if the `window` would work).

But as you have an `action` in your list, have you thought of something like this in your view :

```
<ul>
    <router-link v-for="item in items" to="item.link" @click="item.action"> 
       {{item.text}}
    </router-link>
</ul>
```

I'm using `router-link` directly here but you can wrap in `<li>` tags

Hope this helps !